# Inequality-constrained quadratic program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am trying to find the optimal solution to this:
$$\begin{aligned}
\min_{} \quad & x^TAx\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & c^Tx \ge 1\\
\end{aligned}$$
where $A \in \mathbb{S}_{+}^{n}$ ($n \times n$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix) and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonzero vector.

I know I can use the first order optimality condition and would get $2Ax(y-x) \ge 0$ for all feasibly $y$. $x$ is only optimal when this inequality is true for all feasible $y$ but I'm not sure how to get the optimal $x$ knowing the inequality.

Comment: what does $1/c$ mean when $c$ is a vector?

Comment: good point. then my intuition is no where near correct. any pointers would help

Comment: it's a pretty common notation used in popular convex optimization textbook's like Boyd's, but I'll add it anyway

Answer (score 1):

assuming $A$ is symmetric positive definite, it has a Cholesky decompostions $A= W^T W.$   Taking $y= Wx,$ the objective becomes $y^T y$ which is just its squared length. The constraint is $(c^T W^{-1}) y \geq 1$ where the point nearest the origin is a multiple of the vector $(c^T W^{-1})$ as a row, or ${W^{-1}}^T c$ as a column. Something like that.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. So I'm not sure if Cholesky decomposition would still work then.

Comment: i think this needs to be solved using the first order optimality condition but not quite sure how to apply it

Answer (score 1):

At optimality $c^Tx=1$ (if $c^Tx>1$, you can always rescale $x$ without making the objective function worse). Minimizing a quadratic function under a linear equality constraint [is easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints) and boils down to solving a linear system.